# jQuery navigation - external loading (or perhaps it isn't... I'm having trouble figuring it out)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I find my problem a little bit difficult to ask about, because I don't know how to explain it or how to even start searching for an answer. I will try here because I'm really stuck and I know Stack Overflow always helps me find a way to keep going and learning. See if someone can open my eyes.

What I'm looking forward to is to achieve a similar effect as the navigation in uzik's [page](http://www.uzik.com/):  (see the grey banner at the bottom? well, that). So, yes, I know how to overlap two divs and just slide one or the other on top using jQuery. In fact, there's this [demo](http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/)  that shows how to do that and more beautifully (very interesting link to keep ;) ).

But my problem is something else. Notice that when you click on the slider that will overlap the main content, **the url changes**. That's what I would like to achieve and I don't know if both divs (main content and overlapping content) are on the same page and the url is being changed using some js; or if the overlapping div is, in fact loaded from an external source.

In my case, I would like to load from an external page. Say, for instance, someurl.com and someurl.com/blog. The aim is, having both preloaded (I guess) to slide one on top of the other.

Is this even possible? I would like to think it is. I can follow js and jQuery instructions more or less, but need some guidance as to where to start off searching info, specifically on the loading content from some other url part.

Any tip is appreciated.

Kind regards, Bea.

Comment: `Same origin policy`. You won't have much luck trying to grab an external url's content via javascript. You would need to get the external content via a server side language

Comment: It's the same domain though, only a different page. Is that also a problem regarding the same origin policy?

Comment: Ah I see, then in that case, no that should not be an issue ;)